# What is the 'dimensionality' in solid state materials?

Tags: condensed-matter, spacetime-dimensions

In the context of condensed matter physics, when it is referred to a '1D', '2D' or '3D' material, what context is this dimensionality understood in? Real space? momentum space? or something else? We can take graphene as an example, but any other example would be nice, too.

Answer (score 1):

There is an one to one correspondence between momentum space and real space through Fourier Transform. Thus a crystal in real space has the same dimensionality in momentum space also. However one must remember that when we say 2D crystals we do not necessarily mean exactly 2D. There are several things as multilayered 2d crystals such as MoS2 etc..

Comment: So you are saying the dimensionality is in the sense of the dimension in / of the real (or momentum) space?

Comment: yes. exactly that.